# Minimum length solution to system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the system $Ax = b$, where $A$ is a $3 × 4$ matrix with real entries. Assuming there
is at least one solution to the system, show that the solution with minimal length is $A^Tu$,
where $u$ is a solution to the system $AA^Tu = b$.

Where can I find a proof of this theorem? Is there a name for this result?

Answer (score 1):

The result is known as Least Square Solution (LSS) to the approximation Ax ~ b.
Def: x* is the least square solution to an inconsistent matrix equation Ax = b where A is mxn matrix  provided ||Ax*-b||<= ||Ax-b|| for all x ε R^n
Note ||.||^2 is the Euclidean norm or ||x||^2 = (x,x) is the inner product of x and itself.

A Least-Squares Solution (LSS) of Ax= b is a solution x* such that Ax*= b* of the consistent equation Ax= b i.e. b* is the projection b_proj of b to the range space.
It follows from the geometry that if b = b_proj + b_perp, Ab = Ab* and Ab_perp = 0

Theorem The LSS to Ax=b is the solution to the matrix equation (A^t A) x = A^t b

Algorithm

1. compute A^t A and A^t b
2. Form the augumented matrix [ A^t A | A^t b] and row reduce.
3. This equation is always consistent, and any solution is a LSS.

Let A be a mxn matrix and b be a mx1 vector
Theorem
The following are equivalent

1. Ax=b has a LSS
2. Columns of A are linearly independent
3. (A^t A) is invertible and LSS is x* = (A^t A)^(-1) A^t b

See the link to The Method of Least Square below
https://textbooks.math.gatech.edu/ila/least-squares.html

Comment: Just had a closer look at your answer, I'm not sure how this relates to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let us think about this geometrically.

The set of solutions to $Ax=b$, if consistent, forms an affine subspace of the form $x_p+NS(A)$, where $x_p$ is any (particular) solution to $Ax=b$ and $NS(A)$ is the nullspace of $A$. Essentially, the solution set to $Ax=b$ is some translated subspace ($NS(A)$) by $x_p$.

Now, among the vectors in this translated subspace $x_p + NS(A)$, the one with the least length is the one that is perpendicular to the subspace $NS(A)$. To convince yourself of this, imagine $NS(A)$ is some plane in 3-space, and consider all vectors in some shifted plane $x_p + NS(A)$. The one that has least length is orthogonal to $NS(A)$. So this least length vector is in $NS(A)^\perp$.

But we know $NS(A)^\perp = CS(A^T)$, the columnspace of $A^T$. And as vectors in $CS(A^T)$ has the form $A^T u$ for some $u$, this means we are looking for some $A^T u$ that satisfies $Ax=b$, namely $AA^Tu = b$.